# do while works one step slower

Tags: c, printf, scanf, do-while

i have a problem with do-shile loop and i dont know why this hapening even after debuging(i have alot of exp in c but i dont know why this happen here :( )
here is the code:

```
    int n;
n = 0;
do{
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
} while (n != -1);
printf("out!");
```

and here is the out put:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2rBZ.png)
as you can see, the echo of n is one step back of now of the input.
also in the debuging i see for the first input, we must put tow inputs but without debug(setp by step) its just needs one input but the output is the same

Comment: Please put the output back into the question.

Comment: As text, not an image please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a newline in the scanf format.

Whitespace (which includes newlines) in a scanf format does not match whitespace in the input.  Instead, it causes scanf to read and discard whitespace characters until it finds a non-whitespace character on the input, which it leaves as the next character to be read.

So in your case, the first `scanf` call won't return until it gets to the `2` in the input.  That will be left for the second scanf to read, but will need to be entered before that first scanf can complete (and the first printf called).

Remove that newline (the `%d` format automatically ignores preceding whitespace, including any newlines that may be left from earlier scanfs) and it should work as you expect.